# Any way to turn off the display of MacBook automatically when closing the lid without sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I use my Mac (2021 MBP 14') for music when studying and would like to close the lid and have the music (from Spotify) continue to play by following [this tutorial](https://windowsreport.com/mac/play-music-lid-closed-mac/) on stopping MacBook from sleeping with closed lid.

I then discovered that by doing so, the display will remain on until..I'm not sure when but there was once I forgot to re-enable sleep, closed the lid and the screen was lit for 1 and a half hours straight without any usage.

So is there any way to "tell" the Mac to turn off the screen when closing the lid? For now I have been pressing the power button to lock the Mac followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> to turn off the display before closing the lid.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SYou're looking for clamshell mode.

How are you verifying the screen is on while closed? Even with sleep disabled, the screen should turn off when closed UNLESS 'Turn display off' is set to Never.

```
System Preferences > Battery > Turn display off after:
```

Ampethamine (free) is one of the preferred apps to manage system sleep, and it has a Quick Preference to manage Display Sleep separate from System Sleep.

Comment: About that how I am verifying, I simply closed the lid, 3 seconds later I lifted the lid up like 3mm or something, where normally it will not be enough to wake the Mac, but in this case I see there is still light from the display. Now that I think about it, my 'Turn display off' is set to 2 minutes and it might be off by 2 minutes and I was probably just assuming that the display is on just because the Mac was hot for no apparent reason. Thanks for the answer! I will just mark it as the  accepted one because why not

Comment: Oh and by the way how do you rely on Ampethamine to achieve the result of turning off the display without putting Mac to sleep?

Comment: Quick Preference > Allow Display Sleep in Amphetamine. Then you start a keep awake session as normal